# Starting Activity with some `put extra` onClick of a recyclerView Item

Tags: android, parameter-passing, android-recyclerview

I want to pass an object from one activity to another on click of Item in Recycler view. Now the thing I have came across for handling item click is:

```
public static class RecylerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    public RecylerViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Context context = itemView.getContext();
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailAct.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Obviously it is an **inner** **static** class. Now I have to call the object which I am inflating in the item to be passed into next Activity. And that object is in its outer class i.e in **onBindViewHolder** of Adapter class.
So When I researched, I found that We should *not call variables of outer class from inner **static** class*. I also thought of creating a constructor in my activity to pass object but then then I might be wrong beacause that way I am not going to create any activity. Now  I am totally confused how to do this. Please help

Answer (score 0):

In your `onClick()` method, you can call `getPosition()` which will give you the position in you dataset of the clicked item. With that information, you access the properties in your dataset particular item, and pass them to your activity via `putExtra()` intent method.

Comment: getPosition() is now deprecated and replaced with getAdapterPosition()